# How to get memory address of object in LLVM pass

Tags: clang, llvm, instrumentation, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

source line:

```
// mutex M
M.lock()
```

After compiling and linking, I got this line in instrumentated IR code:

```
call void @_ZNSt5mutex4lockEv(%"class.std::mutex"* nonnull dereferenceable(40) bitcast ({ %union.pthread_mutex_t }* @M to %"class.std::mutex"*))
```

In LLVM pass once I get the hold of M.lock() instruction using `CallInst *CI = cast<CallInst>(&i);`, how can I get the memory address of M?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the instruction as an `Instruction *`, `->getArgOperand(0)` returns a `Value *`. That value is M, more or less. You don't know its final numerical value because that's chosen by the linker, but you can use M in any expression, and the linker will assign the right numerical value to your use when it's processing all the other uses.

In this case `isa<ConstantExpr>(M)` returns true, because the argument is a cast. Put differently, `auto C = dyn_cast<ConstantExpr>(M)` returns a `ConstantExpr*`, and `C->getOperand(0)` returns the actual M (and `C->getOpcode()` returns a cast opcode). In many other examples, M would have another type than `ConstantExpr`. If you want to do comprehensive analysis you'll typically to consider have many cases. Unit testing helps.

Comment: Thanks! I did get an idea of what the deal with Value* from your answer. So is it okay to say that I could simply pass that Value* as argument value to my hook function foo(mutex* m) and LLVM would internally make it work. If yes, could you please tell what's the argument Type would be for mutex*?

Comment: That depends on the frontend that parsed the source language and generated the IR. Mostly the names are mangled. Best is perhaps to [ask a function what argument type it takes](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1FunctionType.html#a20cdc3911828248e70dbeae018106b76).